# JTextArea - very small size with long text

Tags: java, swing, textarea, sizing

I'm using a JTextArea to display a long text

```
JTextArea _definition = new JTextArea(5, 50);
```

with word-wrap

```
_definition.setLineWrap(true);
_definition.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

embedded in a JScrollPane

```
add(new JScrollPane(_definition), gbc);
```

All that is part of a JPanel with the GridBagLayout.

Everything is working fine with shorter text, but when I add a long text with line wraps and the scrollbar is required, pack() goes south and all components have just a minimum size and the dialog is unusable (it's not only the TextArea that is affected).

I've tried to figure out what is going on, but all I could figure out is that is has to do with the text in the TextArea. I'm stuck .. any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work .. Ross's answer was giving me some better terms to search for, so thanks for helping me by pointing in the right direction!

```
 pack();
 _definition.setSize(_definition.getPreferredSize());
 pack();
```

So double-packing plus some extra ... strange behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Try calling `pack()` twice. JTextArea has some odd behavior [as described in this entry in the Java bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4924163). It reports its preferred size initially as a single-line entry that is very wide (e.g. one row, a thousand columns). Once it realizes that it is a certain width, it will then report a correct preferred size for the number of rows it needs.

I've had to do a number of different things to get around this behavior, including subclassing JTextArea and modifying its behavior to be a little smarter. Double `pack()` may work for you in this case, or you may have to resort to more complicated tweaking depending on how everything in your layout fits together.

Comment: Double pack()-ing didn't work for me .. can you elaborate on "more complicated tweaking" .. thanks!

Comment: A first step is probably to try subclassing JTextArea and track every time the get*Size() methods are called, and see if the results are what you expect them to be.